# SQL query - aggregating by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I seem to have some hard time figuring out the right query for my problem, any help will be appreciated.

I have **2** tables :

**PatientExercise** `(PatientID,ExerciseID,StartDate,EndDate)-first 3 are PK`

**PatientHistory** `(PatientID,ExerciseID,CompletionDate) -all 3 are PK`

I'm trying to build 2 queries.

The first needs to return the exercise completion percentage for a given Patient for a week (by days), and the second query should do the same for 3 months(by weeks).

for example :

PatientExercise:
there cant be any overlap dates in this table(PatientExercise)

```
PatientID ExerciseID  StartDate    EndDate
---------------------------------------------
111           13     2013-04-28   2013-08-28
111           14     2013-04-28   2013-08-28
111           16     2013-04-28   2013-05-07
111           17     2013-05-09   2013-08-28
222           13     2013-04-28   2013-08-28
222           14     2013-04-28   2013-08-28
.
.
.
```

PatientHistory

```
PatientID ExerciseID  CompletionDate 
------------------------------------
111           13     2013-04-28 
111           13     2013-05-05 
111           14     2013-05-05
111           13     2013-05-06 
111           14     2013-05-06
111           13     2013-05-07 
111           14     2013-05-07
111           16     2013-05-07 
111           13     2013-05-08
```

for patientID 111 with a giving start of the week date of 2013-05-05
query 1  results:

```
day            Completion
-------------------------------
2013-05-05        66%             ->> there are 3 exe's that has to be done on this date (13,14,16) and according to history he did only 2 (13,14) so 2/3 = 66%
2013-05-06        66%
2013-05-07       100%
2013-05-08        50%  
2013-05-09         0%
2013-05-10         0%
2013-05-11         0%
```

and the same for second query but instead of day --> week.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

Add the week filter as per your need.

**Query 1**:

```
select CONVERT(datetime,CompletionDate), 100*count(*)/(select count(*) from tbl1
                            where CONVERT(datetime,CompletionDate) 
                                   between CONVERT(datetime,StartDate) 
                                   and CONVERT(datetime,EndDate) and PatientID=111) as completionRate
from 
  tbl2 b
where PatientID=111
group by CONVERT(datetime,CompletionDate)
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e93c/2)**:

```
|         DATE(COMPLETIONDATE) | COMPLETIONRATE |
-------------------------------------------------
| April, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000 |        33.3333 |
|   May, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000 |        66.6667 |
|   May, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000 |        66.6667 |
|   May, 07 2013 00:00:00+0000 |            100 |
|   May, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 |             50 |
```

**NOTE** : This is not an optimized way of doing it but it works. Also you need to heck for 0 otherwise it will throw divide by 0 error.

Comment: The query in your answer won't compile in SQL Server.

Comment: I have tested in the fiddle with SQL Server 12 as the database and the fiddle is working.

Comment: Ohh...  got the problem..Thanks for pointing .. :) It was for MYSQL but later realized it was for SQL server so forgot to edit..

Comment: Ah yes, that kind of problem can be quite annoying actually, especially when the last version you tested on SQL Fiddle differs very little from the one you end up posting and so there's little chance someone else might notice that for you if you yourself didn't. I'm glad for you that the difference was more obvious in your case. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
;WITH ExercisesNeeded AS(
SELECT
    PatientID,
    COUNT(1) ExercisesNeeded
FROM PatientExercise
WHERE '2013-05-05' BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
GROUP BY PatientID
),
ExercisesDone AS(
SELECT PatientID,
       CompletionDate,
       COUNT(ExerciseID) ExercisesDone
FROM PatientHistory
GROUP BY PatientID,
         CompletionDate
)
SELECT
    ED.PatientID,
    CompletionDate,
    ExercisesDone * 100 / NULLIF(ExercisesNeeded, 0) AS PercentDone
FROM ExercisesNeeded EN
JOIN ExercisesDone ED
    ON ED.PatientID = EN.PatientID
WHERE CompletionDate >= '2013-05-05'
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b52c5/17)